# sql subqueries, grouping and a bit of math

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, group-by, jet-sql

this counts all items in B and groups on A:

```
SELECT A, Count(*) AS [Count All]
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY A;
```

this counts all 1s in B and groups on A:

```
SELECT A, Count(*) AS [Count Ones]
FROM MyTable
WHERE
     MyTable.[B]='1' 
GROUP BY A;
```

How do I put both columns (all and 1s) and additionally, how could I show percentage in another row

table columns:

[A]  [COUNT ALL]  [COUNT ONES]  [ONES/ALL]

Comment: RE: "how could I show percentage in another row" - you mean another **column** presumably?

Comment: Is this Sql Server or another flavor of RDBMS?

Comment: @Daniel: It would be nice to see a results mockup. E.g. what do you expect the output to look like?

Comment: I'm trying to get it to work through Jet SQL (Access)

Comment: percentage is ones in(over) all

Comment: @Daniel I restored my answer. Since you included it in your question. You should note I changed the alias on Percent because it caused a syntax error

Comment: Yes, I meant to correct that, but [Percentage] works as-well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since its MS-ACCESS you can use iif instead of case

```
SELECT 
     Table1.A, 
     Sum(IIf([B]=1,1,0)) AS Count1, 
     Count(Table1.A) AS total, 
     (Sum(IIf([B]=1,1,0))/ Count(Table1.A)) * 100 AS percentofones
FROM 
     Table1
GROUP BY 
     Table1.A;
```